# Linux find files in subdirectories by extension (.txz) then move them to specified directory using regular expressions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, regex

I have mirrored a directory from a server with a large number of sub directories, each of which contain a .txz package and the usual .txt and descriptor files.
What I would like to do is the following:

Find/locate all the .txz files within all the sub directories, then move them all to a specific folder; using regular expressions.
What would the regular expression to use be, in bash on slackware linux? Thanks

Comment: [How to move or copy files listed by 'find' command in unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368872/how-to-move-or-copy-files-listed-by-find-command-in-unix)

Comment: What's your need for regular expressions?  Are you just trying to match against the .txz filename, or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as you asked it:

```
find -regex '.*\.txz' -type f -exec mv {} '/destination/path' \;
```

Note however that the use of regex is unnecessary for your task. The command below would have worked as well:

```
find -name '*.txz' -type f -exec mv {} '/destination/path' \;
```

You can also do it without the use of anything apart from bash and mv. This uses pattern search and the shell's globstar option.

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in ./**/*.txz; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && mv "$file" '/destination/path'
done
shopt -u globstar
```